# How to Use CTRL + Z in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

it presses the enter but it doesnt perfrom Ctrl + Z so how can i make it so the program first presses ENTER and than Cltr + Z

```
afile = open("test.txt", "r")
        for line in afile:
            pieces = line.split("\n")
            test = pieces[0]
            donotuse = pieces[1]

            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.send_keys(test)
            actions.perform()

            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            actions.perform()

            actions = ActionChains(driver)
  
        actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('Z').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: Maybe try `actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('Z').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`

Comment: nope still does nothing

Comment: wait ill put in full code

Comment: could you try action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 'z')

Comment: your `actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('Z').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()` line is called out of the `for` loop so the `actions` object is not initialized there

Comment: actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("z").perform() try this as well.

Comment: @Eliyahu Do you know how to get it in the loop?

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya Both tried doesnt work thanks

Comment: @ArundeepChohan also tried but thanks

Comment: sure, just add tabulation so it will be same amount of white spaces starting from the left as the lines above it. It's a basic python syntax

Comment: Great. So please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with using `Ctrl+Z` in `Selenium` rather with missing correct indentation for `actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('Z').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()` code line that makes this line out of the `for` loop where `actions` object is not initialized.

Comment: Could you explain to me how to insert that into the code?

Comment: To insert what? The tabulation? Just align the `actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('Z').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()` code text same amount of white spaces from the left as the other code lines after (inside) the `for` loop.
Read about code Indentation in python 
For example here https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Answer (score 0):

Awnserd See comments:
add tabulation so it will be same amount of white spaces starting from the left as the lines above it